# How to set bits in an initially null char in mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a char(1) which can be default null in a Mysql table. I'm trying to use all the eight bits of this char as individual flags.

The problem I face is that when I try to set a combination of bits when the initial value of the field is null, it gets messed up, and the true value (say 254) does not get reflected.

Is there a way to set the bits of the (initially null) char, without making any extra queries to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use IFNULL in your Query .. If the value in the column is null then value to the console shown would be 0 .

```
select ifnull(your_columns_name,0) from myDB ;
```